# Printing maximum number of variables

Tags: java

I'm trying to figure out how to round numbers at the moment.

```
   public static void main (String [] args) {
      double outsideTemperature;

      outsideTemperature = 103.46432;

      /* Your solution goes here  */
      System.out.printf("%3.6s\n", outsideTemperature);

   }
}
```

This code yields a printout of 103.46 which is great, except that the next test that is run has a variable of 70.116 and is expecting an output of 70.12.

How do I get the answer to round up and pass both tests?

Comment: why are you not using `Math.round()`?

Comment: Because I haven't been taught that yet. I'm 6 weeks in to learning Java. This is all pretty new to me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to round a number to n decimal places in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153724/how-to-round-a-number-to-n-decimal-places-in-java)

Comment: I'm still getting the same issue as the previous code:

Testing outsideTemperature = 70.1164
Output differs. See highlights below.
Your output
70.116
Expected output
70.12

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first stop when you have such a question, should be the documentation.

[`System.out.printf`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/io/PrintStream.html#printf(java.lang.String,java.lang.Object...)) points to [Format String Syntax](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax).

To format floating point numbers, you need `%f`, not `%s` (which formats strings but doesn't know about numbers specifically):

```
System.out.printf("%.2f\n", outsideTemperature);
```

Before the dot is the total width of the field (which you're not interested in), and behind the dot is the number of places behind the decimal point (2 in your case)

Comment: Thank you! I've been bouncing all around trying to figure out exactly what I should use. I completely overlooked %f. I've been so focused on %s and %d.

Comment: Very much true explanation, besides that you are free to use DecimalFormat which does lots of work done for you.

DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("###.##");
 System.out.println(df.format(outsideTemperature));

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Math.round()`:

```
outsideTemp = 103.46432;
```

**How it works:**

> Math.round(103.46432 * 100) = 10346.00 (rounded to nearest value)
>
> Math.round(103.46432 * 100) / 100 = 103.46

```
roundedDouble = Math.round(outsideTemp * 100.0) / 100.0;
System.out.println(roundedDouble);
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. While this didn't work for this particular application, I'll keep this in my notes for future use.